# toggle betwen two actions Angular2+ ngxs

Tags: angular, ngxs

I have two actions in my state for open and close search bar, how can I toggle between them.

```
`@Action(OpenSearchBar)
    OpenSearchBar({ patchState }: StateContext<GalleryStateModel>) {
        patchState({ isSearchBarOpen: true });
    }
    @Action(CloseSearchBar)
    CloseSearchBar({ patchState }: StateContext<GalleryStateModel>) {
        patchState({ isSearchBarOpen: false });
    }
```

`

Comment: Do you mean you want have a single action `ToggleSearchBar`?

Comment: Yes, and I actually did it. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Action( ToggleSearchInput )
toggleSearchInput(ctx: StateContext<GalleryStateModel>) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    ctx.setState(
        produce(state, draft => {
            draft.isSearchBarOpen = !state.isSearchBarOpen;
        })
    );
}`
```

Comment: You could also write it using the `patchState` shortcut as you had in the question
`patchState({isSearchBarOpen: !state.isSearchBarOpen});`